# Does System.Exception have a built-in thrown timestamp?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, timestamp

Is there a way to extract when an exception was thrown from the exception itself, or will I need to manually add this information to the exception?

Comment: Generally one logs an exception immediately after it has occurred (or, at least, within a few milliseconds), and your log would contain a timestamp. Can you clarify exactly why you need a timestamp on the Exception class itself?

Comment: Isn't "about just now" not good enough?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no built-in `Timestamp` property for the `Exception` object. You can create a new class that inherits from `Exception` and add your own property.

If you're using your exception as a parameter of a log framework, you might want to handle the timestamp directly in the log framework (most probably using `DateTime.Now` / `UtcNow`).

Comment: I guess this answers my question though it was not the answer I was hoping for. The reason I asked the question was to avoid 'catch->add timestamp->throw'-ing external exceptions but I guess that is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

When an exception occurs, and IF you have handled it, then the control will
immediately go to the catch block thats exactly the time when an exception occured

So the first line in catch block could get you exactly when using date object
(`DateTime.Now.Time` etc)