# How do I find the DateTime that an Exception occurred

Tags: c#, datetime, exception

Is there a hidden/buried property somewhere in the System.Exception object that can tell me the time that an exception occurred.

Comment: I don't think so, but you should implement logging so you can write to a file or database along with a timestamp.

Comment: Those other answers answer my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15291328/does-system-exception-have-a-built-in-thrown-timestamp